# Command Path issue with Roxio installed

Tags: java, eclipse

I posted a similar question the other day asking what my command path is. Now I know what it is but when I set everything up and rebooted I started having issues with Roxio Creator. When windows booted I got a warning that Roxio wasn't running. I tried booting Roxio and when I told it I wanted to burn a CD the program said my certificate was bad. 
I did a system restore and everything was fixed so I tried setting my PATH again and I had the same issue so for some reason this is conflicting with Roxio. Unfortunately I need Roxio for work which at this point is a little more important.

I'm new to Java and my class starts next week so I don't know if I can just not set the PATH or if there is a way around it?
I did create the "Hello World" program already and seemed to have no issues. I have also read it isn't necessary to set the command path but it helps in the long run.

I'm going to email my professor to see if there will be any conflicts but I wanted to ask on here as well.

I'm running Windows 7 64bit on a Dell Vostro and I just downloaded JDK 7 and Eclipse if that helps.
I'm also learning from Murach's Java SE6

Also Roxio Creator came installed with windows so I don't have a disc for it. I thought about re-installing but since I don't have a disc I don't think that is an option.

Thanks!

jeremywearsvans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that you set up a JAVA_HOME variable and a JRE_HOME variable in your environment variables.  The JAVA_HOME variable should be set to the JDK folder which contains your /bin folder.  Same for the JRE_HOME should point to your JRE  folder.

For instance:
**JAVA_HOME**
c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_01
**JRE_HOME**
c:\Java\jre7
**PATH**
.....;%JAVA_HOME%;%JRE_HOME%;

There should not be any spaces in your folder paths.  If this is how you set up your installation I would highly recommend removing the paths listed above from your system variables and put them into the user variables for the login you will use to do your Java coding.  Essentially two logins to accomplish the separation of variables.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot. I think it will help.